# Unable to use Hash(#) in callback URLs for AWS Cognito User Pool App Client

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0

We are configuring User Pool App Client for SAML authentication oauth and we want to configure Callback URL having hash(#) in it. But it is not allowing us to configure the URL with hash. Giving fragment error. As we are using angular for front end we need to use hash(#) in callback URL.

Comment: I think these are the [correct docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html)... it says it's not allowed to have a fragment (hash) component.

Comment: i must say that this is a valid argument, as ReactJS and AngularJS apps use hash (#) in determining page components. i say there must be some way to do this on cognito callback urls. if there are someone out there who have better suggestions integrating cognito user signin into reactjs and angularjs apps, that would be great

Comment: I observed that callback url automatically contains #access-token  etc hence it may not allow you to do that again yourself